# Will disabling the Google App Engine confine development?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I am writing a webapplication that has to work with existing mySQL-databases. The client would like this application to be developed using GWT.

I soon found out that the GAE does not support mySQL, so I disabled it to be able to use the existing mySQL databases. Since I am new to GWT I am a bit worried and clueless - will disabling the GAE disable some of the GWT features or is GWT and GAE unrelated for developing the functionality of my app?

Comment: you don't have to user GAE with GWT if you don't want to.

Answer (score 2):

GAE is a cloud server. you can deploy your gwt app on tomcat, jboss etc any server. GWT is not bound to GAE.

[Google app engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/) is provide free support to deploy, maintain  and build your app. and also provide free domain name on www which end with .appspot.com.

Before it only provide datastore support. It is support [Google Cloud Sql](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/) now.

Comment: Its free only upto a point. read quotas and limits section in https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine

Answer (score 1):

You can disable GAE support ( in Eclipse I assume ) without losing any GWT functionality. While GWT is a web development toolkit, GAE is a server platform.

Answer (score 1):

Google App Engine actually does support MySQL. Their Cloud SQL release is a slightly modified MySQL RDB, so it maybe easier for you to use GAE for the API's and the out-of-the-box compatibility. 
https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/

That being said, GWT is not related to GAE so you can use both, independently.